# GCC Linking Error when Building Fast RCNN

Tags: gcc, cython, fpic

I am trying to build the source code at https://github.com/craftGBD/craftGBD in order to achieve the same results of the published paper of authors to observe whether it is reproducible or not for my term project. I realized that I have to install Fast RCNN by running Makefile inside the craftGBD/evaluation/lib folder. However, I got following results when I run Makefile using `make`:

```
/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/bin/python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning utils/bbox.pyx to utils/bbox.c
/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /cta/users/byaman/craftGBD/evaluation/lib/utils/bbox.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
cythoning nms/cpu_nms.pyx to nms/cpu_nms.c
/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /cta/users/byaman/craftGBD/evaluation/lib/nms/cpu_nms.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
cythoning nms/gpu_nms.pyx to nms/gpu_nms.cpp
/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /cta/users/byaman/craftGBD/evaluation/lib/nms/gpu_nms.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
skipping 'pycocotools/_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'utils.cython_bbox' extension
['-Wno-cpp', '-Wno-unused-function'] .c ['-I/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include', '-I/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/include/python2.7', '-c'] ['-Wno-cpp', '-Wno-unused-function'] ['-I/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include', '-I/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/include/python2.7']
/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -fno-strict-aliasing -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/include -I/cta/apps/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-cascadelake/gcc-10.2.0/cuda-10.0.130-zjercki4memwdfwjztmfkq2yio2jcev4/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/include -I/cta/apps/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-cascadelake/gcc-10.2.0/cuda-10.0.130-zjercki4memwdfwjztmfkq2yio2jcev4/include -fPIC -I/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/include/python2.7 -c utils/bbox.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/utils/bbox.o -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-rpath,/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib -L/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib -L/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/include -I/cta/apps/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-cascadelake/gcc-10.2.0/cuda-10.0.130-zjercki4memwdfwjztmfkq2yio2jcev4/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/include -I/cta/apps/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu18.04-cascadelake/gcc-10.2.0/cuda-10.0.130-zjercki4memwdfwjztmfkq2yio2jcev4/include build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/utils/bbox.o -L/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib -lpython2.7 -o /cta/users/byaman/craftGBD/evaluation/lib/utils/cython_bbox.so
/cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /cta/users/byaman/craftEnv/lib/libc.a(__stack_chk_fail.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__stack_chk_guard' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Note that my username is *byaman* and I run the code inside the Conda environment, which is *craftEnv*.

The code that is run by Makefile is:

```py
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Fast R-CNN
# Copyright (c) 2015 Microsoft
# Licensed under The MIT License [see LICENSE for details]
# Written by Ross Girshick
# --------------------------------------------------------

import os
from os.path import join as pjoin
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import subprocess
import numpy as np

def find_in_path(name, path):
    "Find a file in a search path"
    # Adapted fom
    # http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52224-find-a-file-given-a-search-path/
    for dir in path.split(os.pathsep):
        binpath = pjoin(dir, name)
        if os.path.exists(binpath):
            return os.path.abspath(binpath)
    return None


def locate_cuda():
    """Locate the CUDA environment on the system

    Returns a dict with keys 'home', 'nvcc', 'include', and 'lib64'
    and values giving the absolute path to each directory.

    Starts by looking for the CUDAHOME env variable. If not found, everything
    is based on finding 'nvcc' in the PATH.
    """

    # first check if the CUDAHOME env variable is in use
    if 'CUDAHOME' in os.environ:
        home = os.environ['CUDAHOME']
        nvcc = pjoin(home, 'bin', 'nvcc')
    else:
        # otherwise, search the PATH for NVCC
        default_path = pjoin(os.sep, 'usr', 'local', 'cuda', 'bin')
        nvcc = find_in_path('nvcc', os.environ['PATH'] + os.pathsep + default_path)
        if nvcc is None:
            raise EnvironmentError('The nvcc binary could not be '
                'located in your $PATH. Either add it to your path, or set $CUDAHOME')
        home = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(nvcc))

    cudaconfig = {'home':home, 'nvcc':nvcc,
                  'include': pjoin(home, 'include'),
                  'lib64': pjoin(home, 'lib64')}
    for k, v in cudaconfig.iteritems():
        if not os.path.exists(v):
            raise EnvironmentError('The CUDA %s path could not be located in %s' % (k, v))

    return cudaconfig
CUDA = locate_cuda()


# Obtain the numpy include directory.  This logic works across numpy versions.
try:
    numpy_include = np.get_include()
except AttributeError:
    numpy_include = np.get_numpy_include()

def customize_compiler_for_nvcc(self):
    """inject deep into distutils to customize how the dispatch
    to gcc/nvcc works.

    If you subclass UnixCCompiler, it's not trivial to get your subclass
    injected in, and still have the right customizations (i.e.
    distutils.sysconfig.customize_compiler) run on it. So instead of going
    the OO route, I have this. Note, it's kindof like a wierd functional
    subclassing going on."""

    # tell the compiler it can processes .cu
    self.src_extensions.append('.cu')

    # save references to the default compiler_so and _comple methods
    default_compiler_so = self.compiler_so
    super = self._compile

    # now redefine the _compile method. This gets executed for each
    # object but distutils doesn't have the ability to change compilers
    # based on source extension: we add it.
    def _compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts):
        if os.path.splitext(src)[1] == '.cu':
            # use the cuda for .cu files
            self.set_executable('compiler_so', CUDA['nvcc'])
            # use only a subset of the extra_postargs, which are 1-1 translated
            # from the extra_compile_args in the Extension class
            postargs = extra_postargs['nvcc']
        else:
            postargs = extra_postargs['gcc']

        super(obj, src, ext, cc_args, postargs, pp_opts)
        # reset the default compiler_so, which we might have changed for cuda
        self.compiler_so = default_compiler_so

    # inject our redefined _compile method into the class
    self._compile = _compile


# run the customize_compiler
class custom_build_ext(build_ext):
    def build_extensions(self):
        customize_compiler_for_nvcc(self.compiler)
        build_ext.build_extensions(self)


ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "utils.cython_bbox",
        ["utils/bbox.pyx"],
        extra_compile_args={'gcc': ["-Wno-cpp", "-Wno-unused-function"]},
        include_dirs = [numpy_include]
    ),
    Extension(
        "nms.cpu_nms",
        ["nms/cpu_nms.pyx"],
        extra_compile_args={'gcc': ["-Wno-cpp", "-Wno-unused-function"]},
        include_dirs = [numpy_include]
    ),
    Extension('nms.gpu_nms',
        ['nms/nms_kernel.cu', 'nms/gpu_nms.pyx'],
        library_dirs=[CUDA['lib64']],
        libraries=['cudart'],
        language='c++',
        runtime_library_dirs=[CUDA['lib64']],
        # this syntax is specific to this build system
        # we're only going to use certain compiler args with nvcc and not with
        # gcc the implementation of this trick is in customize_compiler() below
        extra_compile_args={'gcc': ["-Wno-unused-function"],
                            'nvcc': ['-arch=sm_35',
                                     '--ptxas-options=-v',
                                     '-c',
                                     '--compiler-options',
                                     "'-fPIC'"]},
        include_dirs = [numpy_include, CUDA['include']]
    ),
    Extension(
        'pycocotools._mask',
        sources=['pycocotools/maskApi.c', 'pycocotools/_mask.pyx'],
        include_dirs = [numpy_include, 'pycocotools'],
        extra_compile_args={
            'gcc': ['-Wno-cpp', '-Wno-unused-function', '-std=c99']},
    ),
]

setup(
    name='fast_rcnn',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    # inject our custom trigger
    cmdclass={'build_ext': custom_build_ext},
)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem even though I investigated following questions/answers:

["relocation R_X86_64_32S against " linking Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768267/relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-linking-error)

[How to recompile with -fPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812185/how-to-recompile-with-fpic)

[Cython wrapping a class that uses another library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971872/cython-wrapping-a-class-that-uses-another-library)

Comment: Did you add `'-fPIC'` to the `extra_compile_args` for `utils.cython_bbox`?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, i did but I got the same error.